# Getting a site like Stack exchange running

Tags: support

This might not be the best place to ask this, apologies in advance. Because of the virus, my son's school got canceled and he and his friends are worried about the lost schooling. He asked me how difficult it would be to have a Stack Exchange site running privately for (and by) the kids in his school. I inferred that a fraction of his classmates do not want to participate in more public forums because they do not want to broadcast their ignorance.

Comment: Check out https://www.discourse.org/, it's open-source if you want to host it yourself, and you can also buy a plan from the company if you don't.

Comment: Check out [Stackoverflow teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams).

Comment: I suggest you not to run your own site, but consider the usage of e.g. [Piazza](https://piazza.com) where you can manage your own class. There may be other alternative sites too.